# how to convert jsonNode to BasicDbList

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a `JsonNode` object and I need to convert that to a `BasicDBList` of mongoDb. How do I do that? I need to get the `JsonNode` as a list for my further iterations. Here is my `JsonNode`:

```
JsonNode rnode={"question":"q0009_d2","answers[{"answers":"\"Good\""}],"ranking":"false","other":""}
```

Here's my attempt at converting it:

```
BasicDBList newlist=new BasicDBList();
newlist.add(rnode);
```

But the `newlist` was empty:

```
o/p: newlist is `[ [ [ ] , [ [ [ ]]] , [ ] , [ ]]]`
```

How do I do the conversion?

Comment: I am not familiar with JsonNode. But at first look at your question, I found - syntax error in `rnode` in `answers` and rnode sounds like a document why converting directly into `BasicDBList` rather than `BasicDBObject`

Comment: Thank you..I got an idea of doing it.yes i first converted my node to DBObject and then appended that to my DBList . Then I fetch the elements of the list for my iterations.So it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not work more on `JsonNode` but following simple java code will help you.

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
```

and java code as below

```
try {
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("yourdb");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dummyColl");

    // convert JSON to DBObject directly
    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON
        .parse("{'name':'abc', 'age':12}");

    collection.insert(dbObject);

    DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MongoException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In above code `com.mongodb.util.JSON;` parse given string to JSON and convert to `DBObject`, then it insert to collection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of such json nodes, The below code sample may help you else it does not make sense to convert an object into a list

```
JsonNode root = rnode; //yourJsonNode
Iterator<JsonNode> iter = root.getElements();
  while ( iter.hasNext() ){
//create basicDB objects
// add them to basicDBList
}
```